# Call a Node Http Triggered azure function inside a .NET core c# console application

Tags: c#, node.js, azure-functions

I have a Node Http triggered azure function that returns an array in the response body. I want to call this function inside a C# console application and access the array returned by the azure function. My azure function returns the expected response body when I hit it on postman. However this is not the case when I call this endpoint on the c# application as I'm getting a response object with status 200 but content-length is -1. Please note if I do the same call for a normal express application in the c# application, I'm able to get the expected response

**Here is my azure function**

```
    const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {

    context.log('HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    const adresses = req.body && req.body.adresses;

    if (adresses) {

        //make an asyn function call
        const locationsPromise = await adresses.map(async (address) => await getLocationCoordinates(address));
        const resolvedLocations = await Promise.all(locationsPromise);
        context.res = await {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body:{ data: resolvedLocations}
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = await  {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a adresses in the request body"
        };
    }
};
```

**Here is my C# code I'm using for the call**

```
  {
    string[] adresses = new string[] { "nairobi", "nakuru", "kericho" };
    string apiUrl = "http://localhost:7071/api/Adress-call";
    Dictionary<string, string[]> postData1 = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
    {
        { "adresses", adresses },

    };

    var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData1);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
    using (Stream webStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webStream, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        requestWriter.Write(postData);
    }
    try
    {
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            var pageViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LocationModel>>(reader.ReadToEnd());

        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
        using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
            String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // log errorText
        }
        throw;
    }


}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using HttpClient? Or use 7-bit US-ASCII? The `DataTable` isn't used anywhere. And there's no code that actually tries to read the length. You should remove all this code and start again with just the methods you need - an `HttpClient.PostAsync` to send the request. an `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` to get the response. If you want to check the status, use `HttpClient.GetAsync`. There's no need to encode or decode anything

Comment: To see what the remote HTTP endpoint returns use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to inspect the *actual* HTTP response. Does the response really have a header with `Content-Length:-1` ?

Comment: Yes it returns Content-Length:-1

Comment: And the rest? What is it? How do the requests differ? Did you actually use fiddler to inspect the requests and responses or is this what PostMan returned?

Comment: Postman returns the expected response when I do the call from it

Comment: What does *fiddler* show? Postman isn't a debugging proxy, it's a client. Right now you want to see how PostMan and the code's requests differ. You won't see that by looking at Postman.

Comment: The Content-Length may not be set if the *server* can't calculate it, eg because the response comes from an open stream. The header has to be sent *before* the body. If the server wants to stream the response, and has no way of calculating the correct length in advance, it may not even send that header. Depending on the cliet code, a missing Content-Length could appear as `-1`. Your code doesn't show an attempt to read the `Content-Length` though

Comment: Thanks for suggesting I use HttpClient to make the request, It has solved my problem.I'm new to c# reason I had picked the above method for the Http call.

Comment: You won't find such code in any recent tutorial or article (in the last 6 years), so I suspect this was copied from some really old code. Or a new article based on really old code. HttpClient was introduced in 2012

Comment: Yeah.. found it in another question here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Content-Header` may be missing from the response. If you check the [HttpWebResponse.ContentLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentlength?view=netframework-4.8) you'll get a `-1`. As the docs explain:

> If the Content-Length header is not set in the response, ContentLength is set to the value -1.

HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse are really old classes that are largely replaced by HttpClient, *especially* in .NET Core. There were no nullable value types back when these classes were created, so they can only return `-1`.

All of this should be replaced with HttpClient. The code isn't just simpler, the class itself is thread-safe and can be reused. It *caches* sockets underneath, which means the app doesn't have to pay the DNS resolution tax each time it tries to call the same endpoint :

```
var data=new { adresses = new [] { "nairobi", "nakuru", "kericho" }};
var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
var content=new StringContent(data,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

var response=await client.PostAsync(content);
```

At this point you can inspect the status code :

```
if (response.StatusCode == ...) // Check status code here.
{
 ...
}
```

The `Content-Length` is a *Content* header. It may be missing, in which case the `ContentLength` property will be null :

```
if (response.Content.Headers.ContentLength!=null)
{
    long length=response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.Value;
    //Use the Content length here
}
```

Or, using pattern matching :

```
if (response.Content.Headers.ContentLength is long length)
{    
    //Use the Content length here
}
```

Finally, you can read the response as a string with `ReadAsStringAsync` and deserialize it. That method will take care of decoding the response body :

```
var json=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var models=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LocationModel>>(json);
```